# How to find page that link to my website that's show up in goolge webmaster tools?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

In google webmaster tools there is info that my page is linked from microsoft.com:

[image]

it show 15 links but when I search using google term: [site:microsoft.com link:terminal.jcubic.pl](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=pl&q=site%3Amicrosoft.com%20jquery.terminal#hl=pl&q=site:microsoft.com+link:terminal.jcubic.pl)

It show no results, does it mean that there are no links to my website or is there different way to find linking page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. They are in csv file that you can download from webmaster tools and they are in subdomain.